# How to make HTML underneath overlapping Flash accessible

Tags: css, flash, xhtml

I have a Flash header with a transparent background contained inside of a relative positioned div with a z-index of 10.  The resulting effect allows my Flash movie with a transparent windowmode to overlap and hover over the HTML content.  Unfortunately, the HTML that is underneath the invisible Flash is not accessible.  For example, the anchors will not work.  An [example can be found here](http://www.humanoidwake.com/gear/).  Notice how the very top of the anchor links don't activate the hover state?  I've seen Flash rollovers overlapping HTML content before,and the HTML still worked like normal...  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to prevent this.  Overlapping transparent images and Flash have no way of doing per-pixel click-through.  You have two options, make the entire site Flash, or get creative with the HTML.

For example, your "gear" buttons could be split up in to two parts; an underlying image that has a lower z-index than the Flash header, and the `<a>` tag can be given a higher z-index so the actual clickable area of the link is hovering invisibly over everything else.

To do this you'll need to take a few things into consideration:

- the `<div>` is responsible for housing the image, you could use an `<img>` or a `background-image` style.
- the `<div>` and `<a>` tags must be separate, not nested within a container
- the `<a>` must be styled with `display:block;` so that it can be given a width and a height
- the `<div>` and `<a>` must be the same height and width
- you'll probably want to use absolute positioning to get them overlapping correctly

Comment: I am assuming under your method I could put the CSS background image on the div, instead of the anchor.  Then I could use jQuery to change the CSS background-image of the div when the anchor is hovered over.

Comment: Exactly.  Its not the prettiest solution since the html may not come out as clean, but just be sure to set titles on your href tags.