# Flash player on top of element despite z-index

Tags: z-index, flash

The problem is:
the search autocomplete drop-down is overlapped by swf object despite its z-index is greater
many values for both z-indexes tested - nothing works

```
.ac_results ul {
z-index: 100;
}
#main_banner {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height:385px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

how to fix this?
[the link to mysite](http://coxcamera.ru/contacts.html)

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628013/how-to-make-html-underneath-overlapping-flash-accessible

Answer (score 2):

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://coxcamera.ru/theme/coxcamera.ru/swf/main.swf" width="100%" height="100%" id="main_banner" style="visibility: visible; "> 

<param name="wmode" value="transparent">

</object>
```

hi add `<param>` in object tag. its work fine

Comment: <script>
    var flashvars = {},
    params = {wmode:"transparent"},
    attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF('<?php get_theme_url(); ?      >/swf/main.swf', 'main_banner', '100%', '100%', '9.0.0',    '<?php get_theme_url(); ?>/js/libs/swfobject/expressInstall.swf', flashvars,   params, attributes);
    </script>

this adds <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> to object and helped

Answer (score 0):

```
.ac_results ul {
z-index: 999;
}
#main_banner {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height:385px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Hi your code change like this,

if it is not ok, It is problem with your browser.
i see your site using chrome i cant see any problem.